# How to run the command "netsh wlan show profiles" from .bat?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, batch-file

how can I make it that all the info from the command `netsh wlan show profiles` + "key=clear" will go in to `txt` by `*.bat`?

I'm looking for taking all the info by txt from my wlan all in 1 click. [profiles + passwords]

I have a part of job from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/667510/save-all-wlan-profile-names-stored-on-my-machine-into-a-textfile)

thank you 
have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WifiPasswordReveal` script. Just download it from [here](https://github.com/PassingTheKnowledge/Batchography/blob/master/WifiPasswordReveal.bat):

Comment: Ooo thank you :) [what to add to move the info in to a file?]

Comment: Copy and past the contents

Answer (score 0):

You might consider redirecting the result of the command, that's what it ouputs to the <s>stdout</s> <s>console</s> screen by default, into a file instead using the redirection operator `>`

```
netsh [some commands here] > .\File.TXT
```

Which would create the file in the current directory you're in

NB there's also a second `>>` redirection operator with double greater-than characters which **appends** to the existing file instead of **rewriting** the existing file, that is deleting its contents and creating a new one, unluke the former, which just adds into the existing without clearing the previous contents.

Comment: I got it. it's >> the 1 > del all the 1s befor. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

A Powershell alternative to reveal saved Wifi passwords,

```
$results = netsh wlan show profiles | Select-String -pattern 'All User Profile'

foreach ($result in $results) {
    $result = $result.ToString()

    # split the string by the delimiter, then remove leading spaces
    $result = $result.Split(':').TrimStart()

    $result = $result[1]

    # print the results
    netsh wlan show profile name=$result key=clear | Select-String -pattern 'Key Content|SSID name'

    Write-Host ''
}

pause
```